# Could a SELECT inside of a transaction lock the table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to know if it's possible that a select is blocking a table if it's inside a transaction.

It's something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertClient (@name   NVARCHAR(256))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @id INT = 0;

    BEGIN TRY 
        BEGIN TRAN InsertingClient
            SELECT @id = MAX(ID) + 1 FROM Clients;

            INSERT INTO Clients (Id, Name) 
            VALUES (@id, @name);

            SELECT id, name 
            FROM Clients;

            COMMIT TRAN InsertingClient
     END TRY
     BEGIN CATCH      
         ROLLBACK TRAN InsertingClient
     END CATCH;
END
```

It's a dummy example, but if there's a lot of records in that table, and an API is receiving a lot of requests and calling this stored procedure, could be blocked by the initial and final select? Should I use the begin and commit only in the insert to avoid the block?

Thanks!

Comment: So why are you not using an `IDENTITY` column? @DaleK You're gonna need `UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK`, I think `TABLOCK` is unnecessary

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think that I didn't explain myself very well. I don't want to block the table, so, I don't know if that "SELECT id, name FROM Clients" would be better after the COMMIT, or if it doesn't matter if it's inside or outside.

Comment: @DaleK that's helpful! thanks! and it's a little more complex, I can't get the real code (it's in my work machine in the office), but the real one is a big SELECT with a lot of JOINS at the end of the SP, and I didn't know if that was blocking the tables or if SQL Server ignores it because it's a SELECT and not an INSERT, UPDATE, etc, that's why I wrote "It's a dummy example", hehe, sorry if I complicated the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the sample code you have provided it **is** critical that the first select is within the transaction because it appears you are manually creating an id based on the max id in the table, and without locking the table you could end up with duplicates. One assumes your actual code has some locking hints (e.g. `with (updlock,holdlock)`) to ensure that.

However your second select should not be in your transaction because all it will serve to do is make the locks acquired earlier in the transaction last the additional time of the select, when (again based on the sample code) there is no need to do that.

As an aside there are much better ways to generate an id such as using an `identity` column.